# Constraint to view after nearest neighbour removed

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

Sorry for the title if it's not the best but I really don't know how to explain this in a few words.

So, what I have is a view with a label and a image. There are two casses. One in which I don't need the image, just the label(the most ussual one). And one where I need both the image and the label and at some point I have to remove the image through an animation(this one is handled).

Now. for the one where I need just the label I was thinking to play with the constraints. I want to have the spacing for the left 15 and the constraint to go to the superview, but also when there is a image I want the constraint to go to the image. I'll add a image to make it more clear. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: `UIStackView` can help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you should bind *(Take `@IBOutlet)`* `UIImageView's` **width constrains AND leading constrains** and you need to manage it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like

```
if isOnlyLabel { // "isOnlyLabel" it's just for understanding 
  // Here you have only label not image
  // Set image with constraint = 0 and leading = 0
}
else {
   // Here you have label + image
  // Set image with constraint = 60 and leading constraint = 15 Or as you want
}
```

Comment: Wont you still end up with 30pts left margin in case of only label ?

Comment: Thanks. This one works. Thougth about this solution, but I hoped there is a way from the xib or I don't know. Thanks, I'll do it like this

Comment: @GoodSp33d - Yes you are right we also need to take leading constraint of the Image and need to be 0 when only need to display label. Edited

Comment: @razvan - yes you can do in XIB too and also my answer has been edited.

Comment: Thanks. I added a outlet to the left constraint and width and it works great

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do the same thing from the XIB also.

Select the leadingConstraint outlet from the XIB and create the outlet for the constraint.

It will create a property of type NSLayoutConstraint, then set the value to 0 in case where you don't want to show ImageView

```
  self.imageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0;
```

Repeat the same process for ImageView Width also.